# Using NTV2 transformations in MapInfo

Tags: coordinate-system, mapinfo, datum, gda2020, ntv2-transformation

I am investigating the use of MapInfo to apply transformations between GDA94 and GDA2020.
I am using MapInfo Pro 2019.1 so the NTv2.xml file has 10 entries relevant to Australia. They come in pair wise either conformal v conformal and distortion or 116 to 1028 or 1006 to 1028. Specifically the ones I am interested in are:

NTv2 Conversion for Australia
GDA94_GDA2020_conformal.gsb
DatumID 116 to 1028

NTv2 Conversion for Australia
GDA94_GDA2020_conformal.gsb
DatumID 1006 to 1028

NTv2 Conversion for Australia
GDA94_GDA2020_conformal_and_distortion.gsb
DatumID 116 to 1028

NTv2 Conversion for Australia
GDA94_GDA2020_conformal_and_distortion.gsb
DatumID 1006 to 1028

The built in transformation (probably the 7 parameter similarity transformation works fine. The release notes for MapInfo 17.0  Pro say to enable the the NTv2 by editing the Enabled tag and then implies that the NTv2 transformation will then be used.

However I could not find any way to specify which transformation, and to verify which transformation is being used.

Yes I have the relevant *.gsb files.

Do I have to enable just one transformation at a time say GDA94_GDA2020_conformal_and_distortion ?

If both the conformal and conformal_and_distortion transformations are enabled which MapInfo use?

How do I find out which transformation has been applied?
Or how do I specify which transformation to use.

Comment: From ICSM *official GDA2020* site https://github.com/icsm-au/transformation_grids GDA94_GDA2020_conformal_and_distortion.gsb is the one you want, where did you get your NTv2 GSB files from? Note the distortion for Queensland is not set so the grid shift binary is a rasterization of the 7 parameter transformation. As for MapINFO I've not had the opportunity to use it yet so I can't advise any further. The difference between 7 parameter and distortion grid is very minor, if you're not surveying legal boundaries the difference is likely to be much less than your data's stated accuracy.

Comment: For MapInfo 2019.1 Pro the NTV2 grids come with the installation and I expect are from ICSM. I am testing out various software suites to see how well they handle theList (Tasmanian) data sets. Mostly the conformal or 7 parameter transformation is good enough but we also need to cater for the surveyors. I'll chase up if the distortion grid is set for Tas. Thanks for that point.

Comment: Something that might help: GSB is a raster file with subdatasets, I used GDAL_Translate with -sds to extract all the subdatasets to GeoTIFF, this might help you visualize what the difference is if you take the conformal (7 parameter as a raster) Tasmania and then perform a difference with the conformal and distortion for each band to see how much difference between coordinates warped using either method.

Comment: See this one: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129761/transform-coordinates-in-mapinfo-with-gsb-data